# AzureでのRAID0の信頼性について

Tags: azure, raid

Azure VM上のMySQLでI/Oのパフォーマンスを上げたいと資料をさがしていると、以下のURLを見つけました。

http://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-optimize-mysql-perf/

確かにRAID0にすればI/Oのパフォーマンスは向上する事には納得しました。
ただ、通常物理サーバーではRAID0の場合1枚のディスク故障で、RAIDが破損するので、信頼性が低く、RAID10等を利用しています。

Azure上でRAID0を構成した場合の信頼性は高いのでしょうか。
（曖昧な質問で申し訳ないですが。）

Answer (score 4):

Azureでは、個々の仮想DISKが3重にミラーされているので、複数の仮想ディスクをRAID0構成にすると、丁度RAID 1+0と似たような構成になります。

もう少し説明すると、Azure VM の仮想DISKは、Azure Storage Blob の上に構築されていています。このBlobは標準で、同一データセンター内に3重にリプリケーションされた高可用構成になっています。Blobの可用性構成は、LRS,ZRS,GRS,RO-GRSなどの複数がありますが、最低で3重保持です。RAID0構成をする場合はLRSを利用してください。

下記のリンクに Software RAID の説明があり、その中に同様なことが書いてあります。

[Azure Storage secrets and Linux I/O optimizations](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217122525/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/igorpag/archive/2014/10/23/azure-storage-secrets-and-linux-i-o-optimizations.aspx)

下記のリンクのP36あたりから、幾つかの注意点について書いてあります。
http://www.slideshare.net/takekazuomi/persistence-on-azure-microsoft-azure